# Google tag manager debugger loads with localhost, but not on public website

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager

I'm having problem loading google tag manager in debug mode on public websites. I've tried it on local host and it worked just fine, but when I tried to do it on public page (the same source code) it didn't connect - the page was loaded successfully, but the debugger did not load.

Thanks for your help.

I've tried different approaches how to put that online. (Public free website provider, IP forwarding my to my own localhost but it did not work.